# invalid 'in' operand n

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I wrote example from manual about Backbone, but this does not work.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li'
});

var ex_view = new View();
console.log(ex_view.el);
```

It writes

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand n

But where I changed code and wrote

```
var ex_view = new Backbone.View({
    tagName: 'li'
});

console.log(ex_view.el);
```

Console said

> <li>

Why example from manual not work? And why my code not said closed tag?

Comment: This looks like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799571/typeerror-invalid-in-operand-n. Do any of the answers in that question help?

Comment: jQuery version 2.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Underscore and all work! Thank!